# Letsencrypt with nginx automatic server build

Tags: nginx, docker, lets-encrypt

I have a web server with several Docker containers, one of them being an `nginx`. For easy redeployment, the server is built by a script.

Now I want to make use of letsencrypt certificates. But:

1. letsencrypt needs a running HTTP webserver for verification, and
2. the nginx with HTTPS enabled needs the certificates to start.

The script can't start the nginx first, because the certificates will be missing. But the script can't get the certificates first either, because that would need a web server running. Classic chicken-and-egg problem.

One resolution would be to

1. first create an nginx with a HTTP-only config,
2. run the certbot to acquire the certificates,
3. modify the nginx config and restart the webserver in HTTPS mode.

This doesn't seem to be an elegant solution so I wonder if anyone came up with a better one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a Docker container out there that handles this.

Comment: There are other verification methods. For example some Let's Encrypt clients include a simple web server which can listen for and service any incoming requests. Take a look at Acmetool https://github.com/hlandau/acme

Comment: how often do you build these,  knowing the are issue limits for LE certs it may be best to generate and issue them outside of the container.  I would recommend internal CA certs behind a load balancer, the load balancer manages your publicly trusted certs.....although I do not know nor understand your needs and workflow